# Avoid broadcasting on an argument in Julia

Tags: julia

Consider this toy version of a very real-life problem:

```
julia> foo(a,b) = sum(a) + b
foo (generic function with 1 method)

julia> foo.([1,2],[3,4,5])
ERROR: DimensionMismatch("arrays could not be broadcast to a common size")
Stacktrace:
 [1] _bcs1(::Base.OneTo{Int64}, ::Base.OneTo{Int64}) at ./broadcast.jl:70
 [2] _bcs at ./broadcast.jl:63 [inlined]
 [3] broadcast_shape at ./broadcast.jl:57 [inlined] (repeats 2 times)
 [4] broadcast_indices at ./broadcast.jl:53 [inlined]
 [5] broadcast_c at ./broadcast.jl:311 [inlined]
 [6] broadcast(::Function, ::Array{Int64,1}, ::Array{Int64,1}) at ./broadcast.jl:434
```

I want the above code to return `[6,7,8]`, but that's not happening because the `broadcast` implied by the dot tries to match up the input vectors of length 2 and 3 and feed scalars into both arguments of `foo`. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Surely you should be using `foo(a,b) = sum(a) .+ b` instead directly though   (i.e. call as `foo([1,2], [3,4,5])`)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Simply wrap the arguments you don't want to broadcast on into a `Ref`:

```
julia> foo.(Ref([1,2]),[3,4,5])
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 6
 7
 8
```

Comment: The most idiomatic way to do this is to wrap each argument you don't want to broadcast in a `Ref`: `Ref(myargument)`.

Comment: Excellent remark! I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Is there a reason to wrap the argument into a Ref instead of an Array? `foo.([[1, 2]], [3, 4, 5])`

Comment: I'm assuming `Ref` could in theory be optimised better because it is guaranteed to only contain 0 or 1 elements, compared to an array which could contain any number of elements. However, as far as I can tell Julia does not currently exploit this. Might be worth opening a new question about this.